# Converting OpenCV Mat to array (possibly NSArray)

Tags: c++, ios, json, opencv, matrix

My C/C++ skills are rusty and the documentation for OpenCV is pretty obscure. Is there a way of getting a `cv::Mat` `data` attribute converted to array/NSArray?

I want to serialize it to JSON, I know I can use the FileStorage utility to convert to YAML/XML, but that's not what I want to do.

Mat -> NSArray -> JSON

(I want to send intrinsic camera calibration values to the server)

Thanks

Comment: Another hater downvote... this question has been visited quite a lot of times so I would think it has been useful to some people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
double *d = intrinsics.ptr<double>(0);
```

this will give you an array of 9 doubles. (it's just a cast, so be careful not to let the intrinsics Mat go out of scope.)

or

```
double d = intrinsics.at<double>(i,j);
```

to access a single element.