# How to convert cv::Mat object into NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, opencv

I write this conversion like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:mat.data length:mat.elemSize() * mat.total()];

NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[NSArray class] fromData:data error:nil];
```

However I get `array = nil`. What's wrong with this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Answered by [berak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056772/berak)

[Converting OpenCV Mat to array (possibly NSArray)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20798040/3292503)